# DataGridView Cell value not available for validation when inserting a new row

Tags: c#, validation, datagridview

**Situation:**

I'm writing a Winforms app using C# in VS2013 with .NET4.0.

To carry out cell level validation in a DataGridView I handle the CellValidating event.  When validating I access the user input values with

```
dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value
```

For the validation of existing rows this works fine.

**Issue:**

When the user types something into a cell on a *new* row and then presses, for example, tab to move to the next cell the CellValidating event fires but Value always contains null.

**Question:**

How do I access what the user has typed in these circumstances? I'm thinking that I should maybe EndEdit before validating but I thought CellValidating was an inherently "while-editing" event.

**Edit**

The validation takes place in a validator class the top end of which looks like this:

```
    public void ValidateCell(string tableName, DataGridView dataGrid, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e, ColumnCatalogue columnCatalogue)
    {
        if (!(dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value == null || 
              dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value == DBNull.Value ||
              string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString()))
            )
        {
            ColumnDetails columnDetails = columnCatalogue.GetColumnDetails(tableName, dataGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name);

            switch (columnDetails.DataType)
            {
                case "currency":
                    this.ValidateCurrency(dataGrid, columnDetails, e);
                    break;
                case "date":
                    this.ValidateDate(dataGrid, columnDetails, e);
                    break;
                case "email":
                    this.ValidateEmail(dataGrid, columnDetails, e);
                    break;
                case "int":
                    this.ValidateInt(dataGrid, columnDetails, e);
                    break;
                case "phone":
                    this.ValidatePhone(dataGrid, columnDetails, e);
                    break;
                case "postcode":
                    this.ValidatePostcode(dataGrid, columnDetails, e);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the full validation method?

Comment: @JustinRusso Now added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the data are not yet validated they can't be in the `Cell`'s `Value` field.

Instead the input, as entered by the user, is both in the `EditedFormattedValue` field of the `Cell`..:

```
dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].EditedFormattedValue
```

..and the `FormattedValue` field of the parameter `e`..:

```
e.FormattedValue
```

Note that both are of type `object`, already, after (usually) being entered as a string into the `TextBox` eding control.

**Also note** that for the existing and filled cells, testing their `Value` field is actually testing the **old, unedited** values! So you don't have a problem only with `Value` for the inserted Rows, you have it for all rows!

Comment: That all makes perfect sense.  Now working flawlessly.  Thanks for taking the time to help.